# Can parse float from json to int via struct

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I need to parse a json with a game instruction, but in the backend they change the param previously in Int to a Float (IDK why, but now is like that)

this is the error

> Unexpected error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [ios_apps.HomeResponse.(CodingKeys in _B9BDF2CE76592A42518B3A0888B1E0F5).game, ios_apps.Game.(CodingKeys in _BAE470AF8C81659CF18E4A8D481877B9).counterLeft], debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <53422.434> does not fit in Int.", underlyingError: nil)).

and this is the struct

```
import Foundation


struct Game : Decodable {
    let gameId : String?
    let currentTime : String?
    let counterLeft : Int?
    let counterStart : String?
    let counterStep : String?
    let gameEnd : String?
    let gameIntroduction : String?
    let gamePlay : Bool?
    let gameStart : String?
    let gameType : String?
    let gameUserPlayed : Bool?
    let picture : String?
    let started : Bool?

   // private var counterLeft : Float?


}

struct CounterLeft: Codable, Loopable {
    let counterLeft : Int?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case counterLeft = "counterLeft"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        counterLeft = try Int(values.decode(Float.self, forKey: .counterLeft))
    }
}
```

the response form json

```
game =     {
    counterLeft = "53422.434";
    counterStart = "2018-03-26T07:00:00.000Z";
    counterStep = countDown;
    currentTime = "2018-03-26T21:09:37.562Z";
    gameEnd = "2018-03-28T15:00:51.000Z";
    gameId = 5ab906957889034b223b3ba4;
    gameIntroduction = "Lorem Ipsum";
    gamePlay = 0;
    gameStart = "2018-03-27T12:00:00.000Z";
    gameType = spinwheel;
    gameUserPlayed = 0;
    picture = "/files/1522075335538L.png";
    started = 1;
};
```

I need the counterLeft to be in Int for countdown reasons

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Double**. I run a simple model of your test data, it is working.
Here is the code in swift 4:

```
var json = """
{
 "counterLeft" : 53422.434,
 "counterStart" : "2018-03-26T07:00:00.000Z"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

struct model : Codable {
let counterLeft : Int?
let counterStart : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case counterLeft = "counterLeft"
    case counterStart = "counterStart"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    counterLeft = try Int(values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .counterLeft) ?? 0)
    counterStart = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .counterStart)
}

}

 let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(model.self, from: json!)
```